# Jquery Microsoft Linking plugin: Any way to set a dirty flag when changes occur?

Tags: jquery-plugins, template-engine

If you link a form and a JavaScript object array together with Microsoft's JQuery linker plug-in, is there any way to have it set a "dirty" flag in the object properties to let you know that data hasn't been saved yet?

This code comes from [here.](http://uberpwn.wordpress.com/2010/10/10/databinding-js-objects-into-html-forms-with-jquery-datalink-and-jquery-tmpl/)

```
var myRecords = {};
$("#RecordTemplate").tmpl(myRecords[0]).link(myRecords[0]).appendTo("#div");
```

Now we want to myRecords.filter(whereFunction), sending only these "dirty" records to the server.  (filter creates a new array with only the elements for which the filter is true).

This [post](http://expansive-derivation.ossreleasefeed.com/2010/10/its-the-datalink-that-binds-us-jquery-datalink/) is very useful in making the data linker plug-in work well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [post](http://github.com/jquery/jquery-datalink/issues#issue/7/comment/510769) by [jamiemthomas](http://github.com/jamiemthomas) surely sums up what can be done.